# setiting repeated task in AlarmManager problem

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I trying to set a repeating task using the AlarmManager

the task is to send a broadcast to my BroadcastReciever that runs a service (if it isn't already).

this is the code which sets the repeating task:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000 , 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
```

now the repeating task works fine, but if my application is still running, and I stop it, I don't get the broadcast anymore.

what am I doing wrong here?

edit:

the manifest: (only the relevant part)

```
<service android:name=".TQService"/>
<receiver android:name=".TQServiceManager"
            android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.xxxxx.tq.TQServiceManager"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

the code:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("com.xxxxx.tq.TQServiceManager"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 , 30 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Just to be sure - what do you mean with "and I stop it"? Do you kill the app? As far as I know, if you kill an app, its alarms are gone.

Comment: yeah, I kill the app, but its to simulate an app crash. my service needs to run always, unless the user deliberately wants to close it

Comment: It seems that when you kill the app from the Android settings or a task killer app, alarms are killed as well. But not if Android kills the app due to low memory:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545034/does-an-alarmmanager-alarm-persist-if-app-is-killed-by-system-due-to-low-memory

Comment: well I have an antivirus installed on my test android phone, and even I kill its app, everytime a package is installed its gets back alive. so it indicates there is a way to do what I need

Comment: You could register another manifest receiver for some action that occurs frequently to set your alarm. The Intent class provides a lot of actions, or CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED or so.

Comment: Just want to mention - some users might get angry if your app starts itself when they killed it. Maybe better to be quiet until next reboot than getting uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

How is your BroadcastReceiver registered? It must be in your AndroidManifest.xml file, and not manually registered. The fact that it works when your app is running and doesn't when your app is not running sounds like it isn't in the manifest.

Comment: it is in the manifest. I'll try to register it in a different process.

Comment: didn't work. whats the point of setting an alarm if it doesn't work?

Comment: The AlarmManager does work, that much I can tell you. Edit your question and include your AndroidManifest.xml and the code that creates the pendingIntent.

Comment: does it matter where I running the code that creates the pendingIntent and set the repeating task?

Comment: Ah, not sure that *android:process=":remote"* option on the manifest entry will work right: does it work if you take that off?

Comment: no. that was my first attempt. now I think maybe to try putting the broadcast reciever and service in a different project, make it a library project and maybe then it'll work. any thoughts?

Comment: It really should just work: I have 6 deployed apps that use that technique. Either there is an issue with your BroadcastReceiver or the Intent you are sending. You should check in the output of logcat and make sure that the AlarmManager is firing properly, and then try and simulate the intent using the shell tools to see if the BroadcastReceiver is doing the right thing, but that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. the broadcast receiver works fine untill I killing the app, so I don't know what to see after it in the log. can u perhaps send me a code example that do that? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: well... its written [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED) that all alarms made by the package which being killed is removed from the alarm manager, and the intent ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED will not be sent to this package. @Femi if you found a way to overcome this, please share.